# How to know if the feature variables are "good" enough for building a classifer

Tags: machine-learning

Building a classifier for classical problems, like image classification, is quite straightforward, since by visualization on the image we know the pixel values do contain the information about the target. 
However, for the problems in which there is no obvious visualizable pattern, how should we evaluate or to see if the features collected are good enough for the target information? Or if there are some criterion by which we can conclude the collected features does not work at all. Otherwise, we have to try different algorithms or classifiers to verify the predictability of the collected data. Or if there is a thumb rule saying that if apply classical classifiers, like SVM, random forest and adaboost, we cannot get a classifier with a reasonable accuracy (70%) then we should give up and try to find some other more related features.
Or by some high dim visualization tool, like t-sne, if there is no clear pattern presented in some low dim latent space, then we should give up.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there might be NO features that explain the data well enough. The data may simply be pure noise without any signal. Therefore speaking about "reasonable accuracy" of any level e.g. 70% is improper. For some data sets a model that explains 40 % of its variance will be fantastic.

Having said that, the simplest practical way to evaluate the input features is to calculate correlations between each of them and the target.

Models have their own ways of evaluating features importance.

Comment: hi, many thanks for your answer. I do not know if I present my question in a good way. What I want to discuss is not about variable selection, but an overall evaluation about the whole data set. Simply saying, if the data can be applied for building a classifier. Or if the application problem is interesting (promising to find the connection between features and target variable)

Comment: You could try to calculate measures like entropy of the data or VC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension), but honestly the best practical way is to try to fit a model(s).

Comment: As I understood, VC dimension is a theoretical measurement on the classifier itself, how can we apply it for evaluating the data?

Comment: If the only solution is trying different models or methods, then what is the stop rule?